# Using ccd OpenVPN user can connect , but can't access other devices

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I'm using ccd OpenVPN settings to make static keys for each users.

My Server config looks like

```
cat openvpn.conf
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh1024.pem
user nobody
group nogroup
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
verb 3
client-to-client
push "route 10.8.0.0  255.255.255.0"
client-config-dir ccd
route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.25
management localhost 7505
push "redirect-gateway def1"
#push "redirect-gateway def1"
#set the dns servers
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
log-append /var/log/openvpn
comp-lzo
```

and ccd for user looks like

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.3.15 10.8.3.15
```

When default configuration clients can be accessible from any VPN network device and it can access any device on network , client this ccd configured client can not be accessed from net and it can not access / ping any VPN network device.

I've browsed around , found similar problems , and changed configuration according to them , but it did not help me.

How can I make this ccd client to access other devices and that this client would be accessible from other OpenVPN devices?

Comment: Have you tried changing tune to tap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#policy) specifies that each pair of ifconfig-push addresses represent the virtual client and server IP endpoints. So you should not have `if-config-push 10.8.3.15 10.8.3.15`, but two different addresses. To be compatible with Windows, choose them in the same /30 subnet. Possible pairs are given in the documentation.

In addition, you are putting the client in a different subnet then the one you are pushing routes for. `route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0` only covers ips from 10.8.0.0 to 10.8.0.255 (with 10.8.0.0 being the subnet and 10.8.0.255 the broadcast address, which shouldn't be assigned to a device).

You have two choices, either choose the static ip in the 10.8.0.0/24 subnet, or advertise a route to the statically configured client by adding `push "route 10.8.3.13 255.255.255.255"` if you have chosen the `[13,14]` pair.

Comment: The /30 subnetting ('net30') is deprecated, the recommended topology for modern servers (version > 2.0.9) is 'subnet'. Read this wiki  https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Topology